# No starting word found error in jbehave

Tags: java, jbehave

**My story file contains**

Given I create profile

**Java file contains below code**

```
@Given(I create profile)
     @Composite(steps={
     "Given I clear existing temp files",
     "When I set url as 'url' and input file as 'test.properties'",
     })
     public void demo()
     {
     }

   @When(I set url as '$url' and input file as '$file'")
     @Composite(steps = {
     "When I set url as <url>",
     "When I set input file as <file>"
     })
     public void setParameter()
     {
     }
```

After executing first it gave me error like "No starting word found for step When I set url as 'url'....". After that I added Given statement in addition to when and tried to run that now another problem came, url and file parameter values are not being passed from composite step.

Note : If I use composite step standalone then it is working fine. When I do chain of composite steps then only it is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I changed the use of quotes and arrow brackets.
Inside the "@Composite" it should match with the exact string of the Feature/story file and out side the @Composite use $ for the variables.

```
@Given(I create profile)
     @Composite(steps={
       "Given I clear existing temp files",
       "When I set url as <url> and input file as <testproperties>",
     })
     public void demo()
     {
     }

   @When(I set url as $url and input file as $file")
     @Composite(steps = {
       "When I set url as <url>",
       "When I set input file as <file>"
     })
     public void setParameter()
     {
     }
```

Comment: can you share your Feature/story file

Comment: I just came across similar situation wherein I got the similar error and I found that in composite whatever keyword is there for first step (Given/When/Then), same should be in line with the story file. It does not matter whether your step supports both Given & When, if your first step in composite steps is of type Given, you can not use that whole step with type When. I think this is the behavior of jbehave composite step. Agreed?